# How to make column in view to have correct srid of origin table

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have the following view

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW myview
AS SELECT a.id,
    st_setsrid((st_dump(a.geom)).geom, 25832) AS geom
   FROM mytable a;
```

on a table `mytable` with a geom column of the following type `geometry(multipolygon, 25832)`

How do I make the `geom` column of the view have the type `geometry(polygon, 25832)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to properly cast the column type to include the respective *type modifiers* like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW myview AS
  SELECT
    a.id,
    ST_SetSRID(dmp.geom, 25832)::GEOMETRY(POLYGON, 25832) AS geom
  FROM
    mytable a,
    LATERAL ST_Dump(a.geom) AS dmp
;
```

---

The (implicit `CROSS JOIN`) `LATERAL` construct is an elegant way to expand the result of set-returning functions - the above query does the exact same as your row-type expansion using `(<row>).<column>`.